# Node request object returning 3 dots

Tags: node.js, node-request

I have this code

```
request.get('http://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=CgY4WPCVCczXUYyElegN#q=house+definition', function(error, response, body) {
body.indexOf('a building'));
```

I am using request to pull down the html of a webpage. From what I can tell the page is very big, maybe 45000 characters. I am doing a indexOf on the body for a parameter I know is there but it cant find it. I opened up a debugger session using Visual Studio Code and I say this when I logged my body variable at the end of the text
e... (length: 15000)

It looks like I cant see the rest of the message, and I'm guessing its too big. I tried docs but I dont fully understand why I cant see the data.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is not the length. Output the HTML you receive and open it in a browser so you'll see that you are not receiving the HTML you think.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how do I get to what I want, is it coming down in chunks?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you are not receiving the HTML you want, that's because Google is using javascript to show you what you see on the browser. Try disabling javascript and entering that url and you'll see.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to change the url. Try this:

```
request.get('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=house+definition', function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(body.indexOf('a building'))
})
```